# Populating list with images in PYQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have an external database with images of products.  Is it possible to import these images and display them in a scrolling list, as well as making them user clickable, similar to how a file browser works?

I can only find information on people converting to resource files, but I wonder if its possible to skip that?

Comment: are you using listView or ListWidget ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok ListView and ListWidget both allow users to display content in either list Mode or Icon Mode. So you can set the view mode to icon mode and display image in the list View.

```
self.listView.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode)
```

or

```
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s
```

put the above code outside your class.

```
self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode)
item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/sameold/capture_14.jpg")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
item.setIcon(icon)
self.listWidget.addItem(item)
```

Here is the output for this .

[image]

---

```
import os
files=[]
for file in os.listdir("C:/"):
    if file.endswith(".jpeg"):
        files.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file))

for x in files:
    item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(x)), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    item.setIcon(icon)
    self.listWidget.addItem(item)
```

Comment: thanks for this explanation.  Part of my question is actually loading the images that are in the folder, since I dont know the names, I want to just populate the listwidget with all images in a selected folder.  does that make sense?

Comment: yeah that's easy, just load all the images in the folder.

Comment: I dont understand how to load the images into the widget, in your example, icon.addPixmap()... i thought something like self.imageListWidget.addItem(icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(("/Images/myimage.jpg")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off))  but just nothing happens, no error either

Comment: actually the file part is running as an infinite loop on my machines

Comment: your using linux or windows

Comment: windows, which may be why it also returns an error for _fromUtf8 ?

Comment: @user1938107 :I've changed the file part , take a look.

Comment: awesome thank you, it works great now, although i still cant run _fromUtf8

Answer (score 0):

Not a copy-paste grade answer, but I don't see why it should not be possible:

1. Get the image data
2. Construct a `QPixmap` from the image data. You can go via a `QImage` as an intermediate step and then e.g. use `QPixmap.convertFromImage`.
3. Using any "list" kind of widget you could use a `QStandardItemModel`, setting the item's Icon to a `QIcon(pixmap)` with the pixmap you created in step 2.

Check the qt/Pyqt class reference on the mentioned classes:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/classes.html