# what is the syntax for setting the flow of QListWidget in PySide2?

Tags: python, icons, qlistwidget, pyside2

I would like the icons in my QListWidget to go 3 across before dropping down a row. I believe I can do this using the setFlow method, but I am not sure the syntax for PySide2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating list with images in PYQT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855410/populating-list-with-images-in-pyqt)

Comment: use `your_listView.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)`

Comment: Please clarify: are you asking how to make an icon-view wrap at three columns?